# HttpClient Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I am using HttpClient class to make a web request to get data from server( httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead). But randomly i get this error saying *Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure* I have a try catch block around this call but it does not get caught. Instead I get the error in *UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");* in the IOS App. Is there any way to catch this error or to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ModernHttpClient? If not, give it a shot. It's available as a component and on github. It's a drop in replacement for HttpClient that performs a lot better.

Comment: I tried this in the PCL. I dont see this error anymore, but the web requests are lot more slower than before instead of getting faster. I have a listview with images on which the images loaded faster before but now i see only loading placeholder image.

Comment: Are the web requests slower using ModernHttp client? Could you share some code in the original question?

Comment: Actually I was not using it correctly. I referenced only in PCL and not in Android/IOS applications. Now I have referenced in all the projects and using it. Have to wait and see if the crashes because of this failure went away.

Comment: Is there anything that needs to be done for release mode? In debug mode it works fine, but in release mode i get the System.Net.SocketException for all requests.

Comment: Is there any other exception details? Does the app have the correct permissions?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update the post. I was missing Internet Permission and thats the reason it didnt work in Release mode. I am not sure why it worked in debug mode though.